# PHP array merge: is not an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, merge

I'm tryin to merge an array that I have when it is being created through a function

I have a function, and it returns an array.

```
class myarray
{
 public function getAr($id)
   {
      // mysql query
      while($dd= $database->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
           {
               $data[] = $dd; //there's values in the array when its being populated through the function of the while loop
           }
               return $data;
   }
 public function get3($id)
   {
      // mysl query
      while($dd= $database->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
           {
               $data[] = $dd; //there's values in the array when its being populated through the function of the while loop
           }
               return $data;
   }    
}
```

How come I tried to merge together the array:

```
$get = new myarray();

while($row = $fet->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $arrayAr = $get->getAr($id);
    $array3 = $get->get3($id);
    $new_array = array_merge($arrayAr ,$array3); //this gives me the error
    print_r($arrayAr); //displays array
}
    print_r($arrayAr); //displays nothing, why is that?
```

It says that its not an array?

```
array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array
```

But I can `print_r($arrayAr);` and its like an array inside the while loop, but it doesn't display anything outside of it?

when I tried this...

```
$new_array = array_merge((array)$arrayAr ,(array)$array3);
```

It doesn't display an error, but it isn't merged either.

Help?

Thanks

Comment: Problem 1: You're looping with loops. Problem 2: You're overwriting `$new_array` each time. Problem 3: variables could return empty (i.e., `get3` can return undefined if there's nothing to loop through).

Comment: @jeremyharris my array's do have value, and I'm trying to merge, which is causing the problem. overwriting the array is a different issue that i can look into. the problem is getting the array to merge, and saying that its not a real array when it shows it as an array through print_r?

Comment: Have you tried instantiating it before the loop? Add `$arrayAr = array();` right before the loop, otherwise it won't know it's an array when you try and use merge the first time.

Comment: @jeremyharris yeah I just tried, it still says that my argument is not an array. weird???

Comment: Goes back to problem #3 I think. Debug each output and make sure it's returning an array. My guess is one of the functions is not because `$data` isn't instantiated and the while loops aren't running (because `$database` doesn't exist?). Turn error reporting to all so you can see all errors.

Answer (score 0):

You `$arrayAr` is local variable and 2nd `print_r()` is used beyond of scope of his variable. If you need it available wider, "declare" it before `foreach`, with i.e. `$arrayAr = array();` (or whatever value you want - it is not important in this case, yet `array()` makes code clear).

Comment: I tried addeding $arrayAr = array(); at the top, but it still doesn't display anything.